# moving an animated character dynamically in a WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, webview

I have created a map prospective by using the imagemap  in html and embedded that in a WebView.created the clickable hotspot to show the details of the particular place. now i want to add the get direction functionality in this custom indoor map.

my client's requirement is to show an animated character who walking in a floorplan of a building to show the direction from one place to another place.How can i move an animated character dynamically in the every permutation and combination selected by the user.

please suggest me some idea how can i achieve that.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set Marquee text in Webview for moving text

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String summary = "<html><body><MARQUEE>Welcome</MARQUEE></body></html>";

mWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: i think u didnt understand my question ...i dnt want moving text...anyways thanks for Ur response.

Comment: Ok ok I'm so sorry, I'm not aware of animation, still check http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343. It is the tutorial for animations in webview.